# How to transform an array in to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I nave an array:

```
const arr = [
  { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
  { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 },
  { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 },
  { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 },
  { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 },
  { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 },
  { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 }
];


const arrResult = [
  { name: "aa", total: 28394, featured: 4, noAnswers: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", total: 148902, featured: 13, noAnswers: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", total: 120531, featured: 6, noAnswers: 24170 }
];
```

I come up with this code:

```
let output = [];

const unique = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.name))];

for(const key of unique) {
  let result = arr.filter(x => {
    return x.name === key;
  });
  output.push({
    name: key,
    // need to get the rest of the properties here
    // total
    // featured
    // noAnswers
  });
}
```

The only one thing I can not figure out is how to get the property names.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

#### Idea:

- Create a hashMap so you can group objects via `name`.
- Then, add necessary properties to this group.
- Finally, loop over keys and create final object with name property added back.

```js
const arr = [ { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 }, { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 }, { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 }, { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 }, { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 }, { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 }, { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 }, { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 }, { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 } ];

const hashMap = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.name] = acc[item.name] || {};
  acc[item.name][item.type] = item.count;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(hashMap).map((name) => Object.assign({}, {name}, hashMap[name] ));

console.log(result)
```

---

**Working:**

What I'm doing is I'm creating a new object for every new `name`. So, this: `acc[item.name] = acc[item.name] || {};` checks if the entry is unavailable or not.

- If unavailable, return a new object.
- If available, return same object's reference.

So for any given name, you will only refer to same object.

Now this: `acc[item.name][item.type] = item.count` sets the properties. As we are referring to same object, you are setting property in one place. So if you have duplicate entries, say

```
[
    { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
    { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 123},
]
```

output will have `total: 123` instead.

So, at the end, you have a structure like:

```js
{
  aa: {
    total: <something>,
    feature: <something>,
    ...
  }
}
```

Now all you have to do is merge the name in this object and return the value. You can also create the object with `name` property as default (*as done by [adiga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082296/adiga)*). Thats something I didn't think while answering. So crediting instead of answering.

Comment: interesting getting my head around, trying to understand how it is works

Comment: @sreginogemoh I tried to explain the approach.Hope it explains and helps you

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

The idea is to create an object with `key` as the `name` property and value as the final objects you need in the output. So, that you can simply use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the final array:

```js
const arr=[{name:"aa",type:"total",count:28394},{name:"aa",type:"featured",count:4},{name:"aa",type:"noAnswers",count:5816},{name:"ba",type:"total",count:148902},{name:"ba",type:"featured",count:13},{name:"ba",type:"noAnswers",count:32527},{name:"cc",type:"total",count:120531},{name:"cc",type:"featured",count:6},{name:"cc",type:"noAnswers",count:24170}];

const merged = arr.reduce((acc,{name,type,count}) =>
  ((acc[name] = acc[name] || {name})[type] = count, acc)
,{})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

This is equivalent to :

```js
const arr=[{name:"aa",type:"total",count:28394},{name:"aa",type:"featured",count:4},{name:"aa",type:"noAnswers",count:5816},{name:"ba",type:"total",count:148902},{name:"ba",type:"featured",count:13},{name:"ba",type:"noAnswers",count:32527},{name:"cc",type:"total",count:120531},{name:"cc",type:"featured",count:6},{name:"cc",type:"noAnswers",count:24170}];

/* Our goal is to create a merged object like this:
{
  "aa": {
    "name": "aa",
    "total": 28394,
    "featured": 4,
    "noAnswers": 5816
  },
  "ba": {
    "name": "ba",
    "total": 148902,
    ....
  },
  "cc": {
    "name": "cc",
     ......
  }
}

The advantage of using object accumulator is we can access it like this: acc[name]
*/

const merged = arr.reduce((acc, {name,type,count} /*Destructuring*/) => {
  /* if the accumulator doesn't have the current "name" key, 
   create new object
   else use the existing one;
   {name} is same as {name: name}
  */
  acc[name] = acc[name] || {name};
  
  /* To the inner object, 
      add a key with the "type" value and assign it to "count" value
  */
  acc[name][type] = count;
  
  // return the accumulator
  return acc;
}, {})

// use Object.values to get the value part of the merged obejct into an array
console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

Comment: that is a great oneliner but hard to understand yet, I do need to learn more javascript :)

Comment: @sreginogemoh Added another snippet with comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
var op = {name : key};

  for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
    op[result[i].type] = result[i].count;
  }

  output.push(op);
```

just adding this will work fine. However your code is not the most efficient.
Hashing based on name will make it faster

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
  { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 },
  { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 },
  { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 },
  { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 },
  { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 },
  { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 }
];

let output = [];

const unique = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.name))];

for(const key of unique) {
  let result = arr.filter(x => {
    return x.name === key;
  });
  
  var op = {name : key};
  
  for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
    op[result[i].type] = result[i].count;
  }
  
  output.push(op);
}

console.log(output);
```

The following is the most efficient way of doing it :

```js
const arr = [
      { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
      { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 },
      { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 },
      { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 },
      { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 },
      { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 },
      { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 },
      { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 },
      { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 }
    ];
 
 var hash = {};
 var result = [];
 
 for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
  if(!arr[i].name in hash)
    hash[arr[i].name] = {}
  let temp = {};
  temp[arr[i].type] = arr[i].count;
  hash[arr[i].name] = Object.assign(temp, hash[arr[i].name]);  
 }
 
 for(var key in hash)
  result.push({name : key, ...hash[key]})
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` operator of javascript to grab the desired row from `arrResult` Change your code like below-

```
for(const key of unique) {
  let result = arr.filter(x => {
    return x.name === key;
  });
  var currResult = arrResult.find(x => x.name == key);
  output.push({
    name: key,
    // need to get the rest of the properties here
    total: currResult.total,
    featured: currResult.featured,
    noAnswers: currResult.noAnswers
  });
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ashhaq12345/z8royg5w/

Comment: Your code only works if total, featured and noAnswers are
 the only keys

Comment: Also he wants to find arrResult from arr and not use arrResult to do nothing

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
  { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 },
  { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 },
  { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 },
  { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 },
  { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 },
  { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 }
];

const names = [...new Set(arr.map(item => item.name))]
const output = {};

names.forEach(name => {output[name] = {}});

arr.forEach(item => {
  output[item.name][item.type] = item.count
});

const result = Object.entries(output).map(([name, rest]) => ({name, ...rest}))
console.log(result);

const arrResult = [
  { name: "aa", total: 28394, featured: 4, noAnswers: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", total: 148902, featured: 13, noAnswers: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", total: 120531, featured: 6, noAnswers: 24170 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop to iterate over your array and take a temp array and take map and fill the map using required data and then push your map into temp array like following.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "aa", type: "total", count: 28394 },
  { name: "aa", type: "featured", count: 4 },
  { name: "aa", type: "noAnswers", count: 5816 },
  { name: "ba", type: "total", count: 148902 },
  { name: "ba", type: "featured", count: 13 },
  { name: "ba", type: "noAnswers", count: 32527 },
  { name: "cc", type: "total", count: 120531 },
  { name: "cc", type: "featured", count: 6 },
  { name: "cc", type: "noAnswers", count: 24170 }
];

let result = [];
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
   let data = {};
   if( arr[i].type == 'total')
   {
      data.name = arr[i].name;
      data.total = arr[i].count;
      data.featured = arr[i+1].count;
      data.noAnswers = arr[i+2].count;
      result.push(data);
   }
}

console.log(result);
```